# gcc warns about "unnamed struct/union that defines no instances", but the struct does have a name

Tags: c, gcc, struct, gcc-warning

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct VMCS
{
    uint32_t revision;
    uint32_t abortValue;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) VMCS;
```

when I try to compile my code I get this warning from gcc

```
warning: unnamed struct/union that defines no instances
```

followed by a bunch of errors caused by VMCS being undefined. The code that precedes this is very innocuous, consisting of including stdint.h and a number of #define entries. It does not seem like those could cause errors that would interfere with the struct.

Comment: Is `VMCS` defined as an empty macro by any chance? It definitely sounds like it is.

Comment: One of the few commonly accepted nameing conventions in C is to use all-uppercase names only for macros and _enum-constants_. Change the names and try again. Alternatively you can verify the preprocessor-output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... and a number of #define entries

Apparently you defined `VMCS` as a macro with empty replacement list. Your code is seen by the compiler as

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t revision;
    uint32_t abortValue;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
```

Hence the warning.